# How do I tell if my Macbook supports IPv6?

Tags: macos, mac, ipv6

I want to know whether my Macbook can handle IPv6. How do I find that out?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

All Macbooks built after 2007 support IPv6. Is yours older than that?

Comment: Where did you come up with this 2007 number? All MacBooks support IPv6. All PowerBook G4's supported IPv6. All iBook G4's supported IPv6. You'd probably have to go back to the late 1990's to an early iBook G3 or a pre-G3 PowerBook to find one that didn't support Mac OS X v10.1, where Apple first added IPv6 support.

Answer (score 7):

Your MacBook supports IPv6, because ALL MacBooks support IPv6.

I don't know where people are coming up with this 2007 nonsense. Apple started building IPv6 into Mac OS X with 10.1 in 2001. The very first PowerBook G4 Titanium was current at the time, and like all versions of Mac OS, 10.1 supported a few previous years' worth of Macs.  So you'd probably have to go back to a late 1990's PowerBook before the PowerBook G3 (like a 3400 or 1400 or 5300), or maybe an early iBook G3, to find one that didn't support Mac OS X v10.1, and thus didn't support IPv6.

Now, to be fair, when IPv6 was first built into Mac OS X v10.1, there wasn't a GUI for it, so you had to enable it from the command line.  But still, this 2007 number is nonsense.

**Edit:** Maybe these guys are thinking of AirPort Base Stations. The first 802.11n AirPort Extreme Base Station, which came out in early 2007, may have been the first AirPort Base Station to support IPv6 as a host or as a tunnel-router. Before that, base stations in bridge mode could have bridged IPv6 because from an Ethernet bridge's perspective, layer 3 is just payload, so IPv6 gets bridged just like anything else.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I've answered too fast. I missed the AirPort Extreme-part. I've edited my answer.